# How to generate Hierarchical json data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an Json Raw Data with Parent child relationship.I would like to generate Hierarchical json from flat with parent ID.I have tried below code its working fine but I would like to know how to remove `children[]` object if there is no data in children object.

```
var arry = [
  { Id: "1", Name: "abc", Parent: "", attr: "abc" },
  { Id: "2", Name: "abc", Parent: "1", attr: "abc" },
  { Id: "3", Name: "abc", Parent: "2", attr: "abc" },
  { Id: "4", Name: "abc", Parent: "2", attr: "abc" },
];

function convert(array) {
  var map = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var obj = array[i];
    obj.children = [];

    map[obj.Id] = obj;

    var parent = obj.Parent || "-";
    if (!map[parent]) {
      map[parent] = {
        children: [],
      };
    }
    map[parent].children.push(obj);
  }

  return map["-"].children;
}

var r = convert(arry);
console.log("array", r);
console.log("result", JSON.stringify(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that there might be a better way, but how about just traverse through the `map` properties and delete the ones with an empty children array?

```js
var arry = [
  { Id: "1", Name: "abc", Parent: "", attr: "abc" },
  { Id: "2", Name: "abc", Parent: "1", attr: "abc" },
  { Id: "3", Name: "abc", Parent: "2", attr: "abc" },
  { Id: "4", Name: "abc", Parent: "2", attr: "abc" },
];

function convert(array) {
  var map = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var obj = array[i];
    obj.children = [];

    map[obj.Id] = obj;

    var parent = obj.Parent || "-";
    if (!map[parent]) {
      map[parent] = {
        children: [],
      };
    }
    
    map[parent].children.push(obj);
  }

  for (let prop in map) {
      if (map[prop].children.length === 0) {
          delete map[prop].children;
      }
  }

  return map["-"].children;
}

var r = convert(arry);
console.log("array", r);
console.log("result", JSON.stringify(r));
```

Comment: Awesome, if it answered your question you can consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `map-reduce` can be done very easily in `O(n)`

```js
const source = [
  { Id: "1", Name: "abc", Parent: "", attr: "abc" },
  { Id: "2", Name: "abc", Parent: "1", attr: "abc" },
  { Id: "3", Name: "abc", Parent: "2", attr: "abc" },
  { Id: "4", Name: "abc", Parent: "2", attr: "abc" },
];
function tree(data, id, pId) {
  const [result] = data.reduce(
    ([r, map], item) => {
      const d = { ...item, children: [] };
      const loc = map[item[pId]];
      if (loc) {
        loc.children.push(d);
      } else {
        r.push(d);
      }
      map[item[id]] = d;
      return [r, map];
    },
    [[], {}]
  );
  return result;
}

//console.log(JSON.stringify(tree(source, "Id", "Parent"), null, 4));
document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tree(source, "Id", "Parent"), null, 4)
```

```css
.as-console {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}

.as-console-row {
  color: blue !important;
}
.code {
```

```html
<pre class="code"></pre>
```